# Trigger Build with Ticket Number

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to build a pipeline in `Azure DevOps`.

The challenge I have is to trigger the build once the code is checked with the Ticket number and post checkin, it should execute the Test cases associated with the ticker number.

Is there anyway to accomplish this task? I researched a bit and my research results led to the parameter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in Azure DevOps, if we want to trigger the build based on some condition 
(like in your case, the condition is to checkin the code with ticket number) then as on date, we have trigger tags event and trigger paths event.

You may either checkin the code by adding the ticket number in for refs tags or checkin the code by adding the ticket number in some particular file.

If you checkin the code by adding the tags then you may trigger build based on tags or if you checkin the code by adding ticket number in some file then you may trigger build based on paths.

For more information with regards to it, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops

And then executing the test cases associated with the ticket number can be handled as part of orchestrating build step(s).
Few examples are https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=yaml#run-your-tests and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python?view=azure-devops#test

Hope this helps!!